# Way to export Power BI Report available for further edits

Tags: powerbi, export

I have the following report (see pic below).
And need to export it so that a user would be able to edit a content: to add / change text, for example.

Exporting into ppl (Power Point) allows only to cut-paste it as image
Exporting into pdf (Adobe) allows only to read it, not to edit the content

Please, advice!

[image]

Comment: Might be best to use analyse in Excel option, or use a paginated report, with an export to excel option. Excel is not suited to do table based reporting like you are showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power BI is a tool for interactive visualizations, not for generating editable documents. Your best option in this case is to [export the visual's data to Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data). Click the ellipsis in the top right corner of the visual and select `Export data`:

[image]

Then select `Summarized data` and Excel format:

[image]

Do not expect to get the same layout as in the visual - this is a data export, not a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: I was hoping for some editing tools; but I see... Yes, I can export in excel of course.  :(